# Assign value to FileInput object

Tags: r, shiny

I was wondering if it was possible to manually assign values to a file input object in Shiny. I am attempting do it like this, but it doesn't seem like the file input object is being updated:

```
file_data <- read.csv("file_data.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for(i in 1:ncol(file_data)){
  #Not functional
  session$sendInputMessage(c('file1',file_data[1,i]), list(value=file_data[2,i]))
}
```

File data is structured as follows:

[image]

So row 1 contains the names of each sub-element that I am trying to contain in file_data, while row 2 contains all of their values.

Comment: No. The `fileInput` is supposed to be there to get data from a user's computer via their browser. For security reasons, you can't just ask for any file on their computer that you want. The user must explicitly set the path themselves. If you already know paths and they are accessible from the shiny server, then you probably don't need to go through the `fileInput` object. But it's not entirely clear to me what you need in this case.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for your response. The reason I am doing things this way is because I need my Shiny app to save the state of all user inputs (including the file path) to a CSV when the user clicks a "Save" action button. Then, when the app is re-opened, all of the inputs should be loaded back in from the CSV if the user clicks the corresponding "Load" action button.

Comment: That will not be possible with `fileInput`. Again, it's primary because that's just how browser security works. If you needed to store state, you could upload and save the files on the server somewhere. But then you have to tie them to the user somehow.

Comment: @ChrisHayduk You may have a look at https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html for instance